# How to create simple maven java web project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, eclipse-plugin

I spend more than a half day to figure out how to do simple maven project. Eclipse seems weird IDE throwing all errors.

Steps I did:
1, Installed Eclipse
2, Maven home & java home and path set environment variable
3, Create a simple maven project

pom.xml has error first line 
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

From tutorials and videos i've referred it has java resource folder with version mentioned also there when creating new maven project.

I am using eclipse photon and maven 3.5.4

Error dialog : Probel occured
'Building workspace encountered problem'
'Errors occured during build'

Error Dialog description:

Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'TestApp'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6

pom.xml contents:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.gps</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestApp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Comment: You’d be better off showing the content of the pom

Comment: that's not an error, that is a simple visual indication something might be wrong. But just because something MIGHT be wrong, doesn't mean something actually IS wrong. If you are using an IDE like Eclipse, creating a maven project should be a matter of seconds, not half a day.

Comment: So useful screenshot which you attachement. (sarcasm) Please, provide you pom.xml, and did you try to run maven ? clean mvn install ? What error do you get ?

Comment: @gpsOnCoding don't provide "the first line", show the entire content and mention the actual error message

Comment: have you tried building the project? what is the result of that?

Comment: I think this could be missing building project or you need to update Maven project (Alt F5 as shortcut). For more details, you should go to Eclipse choose Windows > Show View > Others > Type Problems there and check because this can be IDE problem, not maven project problem.

Comment: @gpsOnCoding if that is your entire pom.xml file, a whole lot is missing in it. It's not even valid xml

Answer (score 0):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.gps</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestApp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

This is the very minimum pom.xml content you need. If you have this then the something else should be the problem. You don't need more than this to build a simple basic maven project. I think closing tag `</project>` is missing the the code you posted

Answer (score 0):

```html
<h4>Error was thrown Because it was unable to download any artifacts or resources from repo.
Reason was i was behind the proxy i needed to configure in settings.xml <br/> Located in <br/> pref-> maven -> user settings<br/>
After i configured everything working fine<br/>
</h4>
<xmp>
  <proxy>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
      <port>80</port>
      </proxy>
</xmp>
```